# apache htacess remove trailing slash for multiple domains and protocols

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a single htacess file that handle some domains and some protocols (both http and https).

i try to find a way to redirect all traffing with trailing slash and multiple domains to a page without this trailing slash.

is that anyway i can do it for all my domains and protocols in one statement? i use more then 50 domains and that's a pain to declare all http and https for those domains.

iv'e tried that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1
```

but that does not seem to work with sub directories, for a reason i can't understand that's creates an endless loop of redriection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule instead to remove trailing slash from any path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```